# Extracting digits after certain characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, search, extract

I have a dataframe and one of the column contains `'weak=30'` type strings and I want to extract the digits after `=` string and create new column named `digits`.

I use `re.search` to find the digits but so far its giving an error.

Example data

```
import pandas as pd
import re

raw_data = {'patient': [1, 2, 3,4, 6],
        'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        'score': ['strong=42', 'weak=30', 'weak=12', 'pitt=12', 'strong=42']}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'treatment', 'score'])

df

   patient  treatment      score
0        1          0  strong=42
1        2          1    weak=30
2        3          0    weak=12
3        4          1    pitt=12
4        6          0  strong=42
```

So I tried

```
df=df.assign(digits=[int(re.search(r'\d+', x)) for x in df.score])
```

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 're.Match'

In R simply you can do

```
mutate(digits=as.numeric(gsub(".*=","",score))
```

What would be the equivalent function in `python pandas` ?

Expected output

```
   patient  treatment      score   digits
0        1          0  strong=42     42
1        2          1    weak=30     30
2        3          0    weak=12     12
3        4          1    pitt=12     12
4        6          0  strong=42     42
```

Comment: `df.join(df['score'].str.extract(r'=(?P<digits>\d+)$'))`

Comment: @user3483203 thanks for solution. Could you little bit elaborate what is `?P` stands for ?

Comment: It's how you set the name of the series returned by the capture group.  Look up named regex capture groups, `pandas` just uses that syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with your R regex:

```
df['digits'] = df['score'].str.replace(r'.*=', '').astype(int)
```

The `.*=` pattern matches all 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last `=` and `replace`ing with `''` removes this text.

Or, you may use the approach with extracting digits after `=` at the end of the string:

```
df['digits'] = df['score'].str.extract(r'=(\d+)$', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Here, `=(\d+)$` matches `=`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more digits and then asserts the position at the end of the string.

Output in both cases is:

```
>>> df
   patient  treatment      score  digits
0        1          0  strong=42      42
1        2          1    weak=30      30
2        3          0    weak=12      12
3        4          1    pitt=12      12
4        6          0  strong=42      42
```

Answer (score 0):

The re.search returns a MatchObject and not directly the matched string.
See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#match-objects

If you want the string you could try something along the lines of:

```
re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0)
```